# Установщик Windows (java-приложение+jre)

Tags: java

Привет. Возможно ли создать установщик java-приложения и чтобы вместе с ним установилось jre? Как это сделать?

Comment: можно, как минимум можно весь хлам запихать в exe с проверкой на наличие jre. Было и ещё пара способов...

p.s. сам не делал, так что посылаю в google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно помню, [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) позволяет собрать для приложения установщик, который проверит в ходе установки наличие на машине нужной версии JRE и установит при необходимости.

Comment: Сделал при помощи Advanced Installer. Там и классический установщик + установка JRE. Да вот только в приложении 1 класс только работает, другие нет. Не пойму почему